# Using Outer Scope Variables in List Comprehensions in CUE Lang

Tags: cuelang

In CUElang, I noticed that variables defined in list comprehensions don't inherit the outer scope directly. I'm getting an error when trying to use an outer scope boolean variable within a list comprehension. Here's an minimal working example that demonstrates the issue:

```
#GetCPUSet: {
    parallelize: bool

    if parallelize == true {
        cpuSet: "1-2"
    }
    if parallelize == false {
        cpuSet: "3-4"
    }
}

_experimentInput: "test_A1,test_A2|test_B2"
_experiments:      strings.Split(_experimentInput, "|")

parallelize: true

experiments: [
    for i, l in _experiments {
        tests: "\(l)"
        setup: [{
            _cpuset: #GetCPUSet & {parallelize: parallelize}
            cpus:    _cpuset
        }]
    },
]
```

I get error messages related to `parallelize` not being a concrete value:

```
experiments.0.setup.0.cpus: non-concrete value bool in operand to ==:
```

If I change the `#GetCPUSet` "call" to `{parallelize: true}`, it works as expected.

How can I access outer scope variables in list comprehensions?

#### Searching for answers in CUE's docs

CUE's documentation on [The Logic of CUE](https://cuelang.org/docs/concepts/logic/) talks about concreteness but doesn't provide much insight to my issue.

Why isn't setting `parallelize: true` right before the list comprehension making `parallelize` a concrete boolean?

#### Searching for answers in CUE's source code

Here are some links to related snippets in CUE's source code:

- ["non-concrete value '%v' to operation '%s'"](https://github.com/cue-lang/cue/blob/63307bd17387651f410e857863af7d8be58bc109/internal/core/adt/binop.go#L30)
- ["IncompleteError"](https://github.com/cue-lang/cue/blob/63307bd17387651f410e857863af7d8be58bc109/internal/core/adt/errors.go#L58)

Unfortunately understanding this codebase is beyond my time and ability for the moment, and I couldn't find anything to help me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the struct `{parallelize: parallelize}` within the `_cpuset` field defines a new block for scoping purposes.  Within that block the field declaration also defines a new identifier named `parallelize` which shadows the like-named identifier from the outer scope.  So the field definition is assigning the field's value to itself -- something that is valid under CUE's scope and unification semantics (albeit not terribly useful).

To solve the problem, we must use a different identifier to avoid this shadowing.  But the new identifier could be an alias or a hidden field so that we do not disturb the original output.

**Alias**

One approach would be to define an [alias](https://cuelang.org/docs/tutorials/tour/references/aliases/) for the outer field using `TopParallelize = parallelize: true` and then reference that alias as the value of the inner field:

```
import "strings"

#GetCPUSet: {
    parallelize: bool

    if parallelize == true {
        cpuSet: "1-2"
    }
    if parallelize == false {
        cpuSet: "3-4"
    }
}

_experimentInput: "test_A1,test_A2|test_B2"
_experiments:      strings.Split(_experimentInput, "|")

TopParallelize = parallelize: true

experiments: [
    for i, l in _experiments {
        tests: "\(l)"
        setup: [{
            _cpuset: #GetCPUSet & {parallelize: TopParallelize}
            cpus:    _cpuset
        }]
    },
]
```

([playground](https://cuelang.org/play/?id=OhxoBvgUPTl#cue@export@json))

If we did not need the outer field at all then we could alias the value directly using `let TopParallelize = true`.

**Hidden Field**

Another way would be to introduce a hidden field `_parallelize: true` and then change both the outer and inner references to `parallelize: _parallelize`:

```
import "strings"

#GetCPUSet: {
    parallelize: bool

    if parallelize == true {
        cpuSet: "1-2"
    }
    if parallelize == false {
        cpuSet: "3-4"
    }
}

_experimentInput: "test_A1,test_A2|test_B2"
_experiments:      strings.Split(_experimentInput, "|")

_parallelize: true
parallelize: _parallelize

experiments: [
    for i, l in _experiments {
        tests: "\(l)"
        setup: [{
            _cpuset: #GetCPUSet & {parallelize: _parallelize}
            cpus:    _cpuset
        }]
    },
]
```

([playground](https://cuelang.org/play/?id=8K0cBPocWeC#cue@export@json))

**References**

Here are some relevant references from the [CUE Language Specification](https://cuelang.org/docs/references/spec/):

- struct literals introduce blocks: [Blocks](https://cuelang.org/docs/references/spec/#blocks)
- scope of a field identifier is its containing block and identifiers from inner blocks shadow outer blocks: [Declarations and scope](https://cuelang.org/docs/references/spec/#declarations-and-scope)
- aliases introduce new identifiers: [Aliases](https://cuelang.org/docs/tutorials/tour/references/aliases/)